# Magento 2: Elasticsearch throw the error "Undefined factory elastic"

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.3.2

Elasticsearch module is not working in `Magento 2.3.2 version`, but it's working in below of the Magento 2.3.2 version.

Throw the error "Undefined factory elastic"

**Below is the error log:**

```
Exception #0 (DomainException): Undefined factory elastic

Exception #0 (DomainException): Undefined factory elastic
<pre>#1 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer->getProductCollection() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php:76]
#2 Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category->apply(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000078f3cf2a00000000500faff8#) called at [vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation.php:67]
#3 Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation->_prepareLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:283]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->setLayout(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor#0000000078f3ce5500000000500faff8#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:149]
```

Any have faced same issue then let me know.

Any clue for this issue? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: This one is fixed issue for me. https://github.com/comwrap/elasticsuite-magento-patch

Hope will help you.

Comment: @RakeshDonga Thank you I will try this.

Comment: @RakeshDonga I checked to that fixed it's not working for me. I am facing issue is something different.

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue, I am getting similar issue after upgrading to magento 2.4.1